# How many people need to be screened if the disease has an R0 of 2, and starts with 1 infection in 1000?

Tags: probability, distributions

I need to calculate how many people I would need to screen to catch a disease in its early stages. If the disease has an R0 of 2, and starts with 1 infection in 1000, and I screen one person in every 1000 - how many people will the disease have reached by the time I screen an infected individual? 
How can I do this on excel?

Comment: What's R0? In what context does this question arise?

Comment: It seems as if there's some information required that isn't here, but this may simply be my own ignorance. (Further, is this screening 'perfect' in the sense of no false positives and no false negatives?)

Answer (score 2):

You really should provide more information otherwise only the people in your field know what you are actually asking. Since you only specified $R_{0}$ and $f(0)$ I assume your growth model is a logistic, which is: $$ f(t)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-R_{0}t+log(\frac{1}{f(0)}-1)}}$$ The probability of sampling 1000 individual in which >1 infected individual is found at time t is $$P=1-(1-f(t))^{1000}$$. Or:
$$t=\frac{1}{R_{0}}[log(\frac{1}{f(0)}-1)-log(\frac{1}{1-(1-P)^{\frac{1}{S}}}-1)]$$
where $S$ is sample size (1000).

Excel code:

```
=1/B2*(LN(1/C2-1)-LN(1/(1-(1-A2)^(1/D2))-1))
```

if $P$ is in A2 cell, $R_{0}$ in B2, $f(0)$ in C2 and sample size $S$ in D2

Comment: Since you seem to know what "$R_0$" refers to, would you mind enlightening us?

Comment: Sure, this question is regarding the logistic growth model, used mainly in ecology, microbiology and medical research. The model is better illustrated in a form of differential equation: $\frac{df(t)}{dt}=r f(t)(1-\frac{f(t)}{K})$, $r$ is often called intrinsic growth rate and $K$ called carrying capacity, $f(t)$ is the population size/number of animal/bacterial/new product sold at time $t$. $f'(0)$ is the grown rate at zero time also labeled as $R_0$, or I hope that's what the OP means. It couldn't be $r$ for sure.